# Запретить системе самой изменять тему

Tags: android, themes

В приложении есть возможность смены тем:

```
    if (color == BLACK) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeNight);
    }
    if (color == WHITE) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
```

Но Андроид 11 все равно самостоятельно контролирует смену тем в установленных приложениях и ставит ту, что установлена в системе
Как ему запретить это делать?

Comment: Зачем запрещать? Вы думаете пользователю это понравится? Ему будет удобнее включить тёмную или светлую тему в системе для всех приложений разом, чем настраивать каждое по отдельности.

Comment: @woesss лично мне как пользователю — абсолютно неудобно, я хочу иметь индивидуальный выбор в каждом приложении по отдельности

Comment: @andreymal и вас не раздражают слепящие вспышки в темноте? Но и на этот случай в механизме DayNight есть принудительный выбор: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#change-themes

Comment: @woesss, а вы не задумывались над тем, что иногда дефолтная тема не сочетается с дизайном программы? В частности, темный режим делает ее неэргономичной, да и можно сделать три варианта - темный, светлый и автоматический... Дело в том, что приложение - это читалка, из него можно сформировать файл на распечатку, темная тема делает автоматически подложку черной, для распечатки это жутко неудобно..

Comment: Так ведь и тёмная, и светлая темы ваши, если они не сочетаются - это к вам же и вопрос. Просто нужно оформить их в соответствии со стандартным механизмом переключения - тёмную тему поместить в папку `values-night` с тем же именем, что и светлую и применять выбранный пользователем режим с помощью [`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int))

Comment: @woesss, все сочетается и отлично используется при чтении. Просто пользователи моего приложения использовали для распечатывания файлов светлую тему - элементарно расход краски с черным фоном и белым шрифтом огромный. А теперь система сама делает две темные темы и выбора нет.. Спасибо Вам за решение, буду внедрять

Comment: И ещё момент: если в системе используется фича "Force Dark" - она может перекрашивать цвета в светлых темах, тут почитайте что с этим делать: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force-dark Возможно в этом и есть ваша проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблему решил:
Добавил атрибут светлой темы в `styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Но решение это не изящное - в задумках сделать смену тем через `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` сделав три варианта - светлая, темная и системная